# Opening software in new window by default

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Kind of crazy, but I'm trying to be a developer using Windows 8 and one thing really annoys me - if I want to open, for example, 5 instances of the command line, I have to right click the cmd icon and then select Open in new window.

Is there a way to open all the software in Windows in separate windows by default? or at least the cmd line. I know I could do WINDOWS+R > cmd > ENTER, but I'm using WINDOWS+S (charms bar?).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`Middle click`, `Shift+Left click` or `Shift+Enter` opens new copy of application.